# Django get currently selected model from a list of models based on URL

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm working on a Django app that has several models: Parents, Children, Schools, CellPhones. Each "parent" (this is essentially Django's "user" model) can have multiple Children, and each child can have one School and one CellPhone.

I have structured my website to keep it as modular as possible. By this I mean that the navigation template is in one file, a sidebar template (containing a lot of links) is in another file, all of it put together by a layout.html file.

If a parent visits the website, it is redirected to `domain.com/dashboard`. In the navigation bar, the parent will have an option to pick a child from a dropdown menu. After that, the parent/user will be redirected to `domain.com/dashboard/1`, where "1" is the primary key of the children database table.

My questions:

1. How do I obtain the selected value after the page navigates to /dashboard/1, so that I can change the dropdown value to the currently-selected child?
2. How can I essentially obtain information about the currently selected child across the entire layout.html file? For example, the sidebar links need to be in the form of `domain.com/schools/1`, `domain.com/cellphones/1`, where this "1" is always the primary key of the "children" table. Additionally, this "sidebar.html" template lives by itself and is only included by the layout.html template. Currently, I am linking to the `/dashboard/1` properly only because I am iterating through all the models in the Children database with the user's ID.

I have managed to obtain a list of all children in all template files (including the sidebar.html), but I am struggling to obtain a single model based on the URL/user's selection.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I obtain the selected value after the page navigates to
>   `/dashboard/1`, so that I can change the dropdown value to the
>   currently-selected child?

Here is one way to do this, but really you need to use a custom template tag to render your dropdown:

```
<select>
   {% for st in studentlist %}
       <option value="{{ st.pk }}"
         {% if request.url.path|slice:":-1" == st.pk %}selected{% endif %}>{{ st }}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

> How can I essentially obtain information about the currently selected
>   child across the entire layout.html file?

You need to pass this from the view to the template, as a context variable:

```
def get_child_dashboard(request, pk=None):
     child = get_object_or_404(Child, pk=pk)
     return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'child': child})
```

Now, everywhere in your template when you want to refer to the child selected by the parent, use `{{ child }}`, for example:

```
<p>Hello, you are viewing the dashboard for {{ child.first_name }}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My problem is that this sidebar.html template (which needs to have links with child_id in it) lives outside of dashboard.html template. The "dashboard.html" template is only focused on the the actual content area. The idea is that when the user opens the dashboard, the sidebar is updated with the links. Speaking of that, can I call one view from the other and tell it to render after the first view has been rendered?

Comment: A template is not a view; you need to render the other template block (from `sidebar.html`) within your `dashboard.html` by overriding it so that it has the context - or use a template tag that takes the object and renders the content from `sidebar.html` - for example `{% display_sidebar child %}`

Comment: Thanks again. It is not possible for me to put the `sidebar.html` inside of `dashboard.html` - there are many other pages like `dashboard.html`, and I don't want to include `sidebar.html` everywhere. I've been struggling to understand these custom inclusion tags. Again, how would I get a single instance of child model across all these different pages, when the templates are completely independent? The only thing in common is the URL.